# Powershell start-process - windows warning while program starts - how to skip/accept it

Tags: powershell, vcenter

I'm accessing vcenter tru rvtools and it worked like a charm for the previous 3 years. Now I'm receiving a windows warning popup whenever I try to start rvtools via powershell or directly. I already know why this popup appears and I'm not able to disable this popup via rvtools. So basically what I need, is an addition to my code, that presses "ok" or skip the popup somehow, otherwise the script won't continue because it's waiting for something to happen. After doing this, the rvtools will continue to work like before, so the popup is more like an information that needs to be accepted.

```
start-process -NoNewWindow -PassThru -filepath $RVTOOLS -argumentlist ("-s $VCENTER -u $VCENTERUSER -p $vcenterpw -d $TEMPDIR -f $TEMPFILENAME -c ExportAll2csv") -Wait
```

This code works, I just need the addition now, is there anything that can help me? The popup is a normal windows popup.

additional info, since its windows popup, its get generated by the rvtools program, not powershell itself.

```
tryed: | out-null,
changed erroraction preferences,
set erroroutput to "NUL",
```

Comment: "I already know why this popup appears" - so why is it?

Comment: Is it what you're looking to achieve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017094/handling-a-popup-box-using-powershell

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen because there is a VM with tons of storages attached, but its supposed to be like this.

Comment: @ZivkoK this one i tryed, I had no luck with this