# Sending mouse selected item into powershell or vbs script?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I added a new item to context menu lets call it "Test", what I want to do is that when i right click on a file or folder, then select this "Test" button from context menu, it will run a powershell script that copies file/folder to locations based on file extensions or folder names.

I need help on [How to pass the mouse selected item into my powershell script ? ]

I am not sure if I made myself clear, example will be if I select file.txt by mouse then right click on it then select "TEST" button from context menu to run my powershell script for copying this file to a location, how can I pass this selected "file.txt" with full path into my powershell script?

If powershell wont work, how about vbs?

Context menu modification will be on

```
for Folder Menus
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell 

for All File Types

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
```

Comment: How are you adding the context menu item?

Comment: And what content are you putting there? What do your keys and values look like? Have you looked at other entries in those locations?

Comment: I added a new key called "test" then a subkey called "command" with value of "powershell.exe + Location to my script", I  dont know how to pass the selected item into my script

Comment: Do you have any other entries in those locations you can look at? Because they should have what you need in them.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/136838/which-special-variables-are-available-when-writing-a-shell-command-for-a-context/473602#473602

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think this is the one close to what I need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125959/power-shell-how-to-send-middle-mouse-click

Comment: That answer is about *sending* a mouse click to something. See the superuser question I linked it discusses the arguments available to scripts run as `command` for a menu item handler.

Comment: Yes, I am looking into it now. it will be a great help for sure. Thanks