# Handle Pop up box with Powershell and -UseWebLogin MFA

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

i have a working script for logging to sharepoint and load the needed file,
but for some account it doesn't work (not azure synchronize etc.) and even with -UseWebLogin
still asked me to select the account and input password and login.
So what i need:

1. First command click on "Pick an account" box
2. Input pass and login

and that's  it

I tried
[that option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125959/power-shell-how-to-send-middle-mouse-click) but still no success, could please help to handle it i have no idea how to pass parameters with **-UseWebLogin**

Thank you in advance

```
$SiteURL = "https://sharepoint.com/sites/..."
$FileRelativeURL = "/../....docx"
$DownloadPath = "C:\Temp"
 
Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
            
    # download file 
    Get-PnPFile -Url $FileRelativeURL -Path $DownloadPath -AsFile
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the parameter `-Credentials` like:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $cred
```

Comment: sorry. i missed that you are explicitly asking for MFA.

Comment: No worries, do you know how to implement this?

Comment: sorry but I don't :(